# Recyclerview los data when rotate display , data is load when push button Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

sorry for my bad english

My problem:  when I rotate my application, all data is lost, I am using a `ViewModel`, my data loads when I push the button, this is my code for test .

https://github.com/elviss116/androidMvvm-master

This is the Fragment :

```
public class MovieListFragment extends Fragment {

    private MovieListViewModel mViewModel;
    private List<MovieModel.DataModel> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;
    private Button cargar;

    public static MovieListFragment newInstance() {
        return new MovieListFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_list_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        cargar = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCargar);
        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        cargar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MovieListFragment.this).get(MovieListViewModel.class);
                mViewModel.init();
                mViewModel.getMovies().observe(MovieListFragment.this, new Observer<MovieModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable MovieModel movieModels) {
                        movieList.addAll(movieModels.getData());
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        }

}
```

this is the ViewModel :

```
public class MovieModel {


    @SerializedName("data")
    List<DataModel> data;

    public List<DataModel> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<DataModel> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public class DataModel {
        @SerializedName("name")
        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the adapter :

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<MovieModel.DataModel> moviesList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }

    public MoviesAdapter(List<MovieModel.DataModel> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MovieModel.DataModel movie = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(movie.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate your phone the activity gets destroyed and re-created, so that is why you're seeing your data dissapear.

What I would recommend is grabbing and observing the view model when the activity is created, outside of the click listener. This way the fragment will immediately start observing the data when it is rotated, but will only be initialized when the button is clicked.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MovieListFragment.this).get(MovieListViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.getMovies().observe(MovieListFragment.this, new Observer<MovieModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable MovieModel movieModels) {
            movieList.addAll(movieModels.getData());
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    cargar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mViewModel.init();
        }
    });
}
```